# What is the difference between the two ways of using the useState's setter?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Let's take some example

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Example() {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    return (
        <div>
            <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
            <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
                Update 1
            </button>
            <button onClick={() => setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)}>
                Update 2
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Both buttons do exactly the same and I'm surprised that Update 2 is working. Official React docs (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) only mentions about first way of updating, second one was found in Redux Official tutorial (https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts#state-management).

So if official React API Reference doesn't mention the second usage, why is it working? Is there some intrinsic JavaScript mechanisms that allows it or is that undocumented feature?

Comment: See [Functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) in the React docs.

Comment: If the new state value is updated using the previous state value, use the functional form of the state-setter function. For details, see: [useState - Functional Updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)